# How to use XSLT to extract elements from HTML files

Tags: xslt-2.0

```
INPUT:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="er:#css" type="text/css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<section class="tr_chapter">
    <a name="c.cno171996.2"></a>
    <div class="section-sect1">
        <div class="section-title1">Heading</div>
        <div class="para">Content</div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is the input from a HTML file, I want to extract the properties of the anchor and also the section-title1 properties.

There are multiple HTML files and i need to extract the same properties from all of them to create an XML file which can look like the below

```
THE OUTPUT I EXPECT:
<toc>  
<entry s="c.cno171996.2/c.cno171996.2">
  <text>Heading</text>
</entry>
</toc>
<docs>
<doc id="c.cno171996.2" src="c.cno171996.2.html" />
</docs>
```

Can someone guide me with this?

Comment: your input and output not match with each other, edit your question and show your xsl you try for this

Comment: I do not have an XSLT, need help to write one